# Connection reset by peer: socket write error, when Transferring Large File

Tags: java, android, file, sockets, server

I'm making a program which transfers a file. In the process of this method, I'm getting the written error:

"Connection reset by peer: socket write error"

The file's size which I'm transferring is 96MB.

(clientSocket is SSLSocket)

Client:

Activity_1 Class:

```
clientSocket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
                    clientSocket.connect(...);
            clientSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(clientSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
                    clientSocket.startHandshake();
```

Activity_2 Class:

```
SSLSocket clientSocket = Activity_1.clientSocket;

final DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                int n = 0;

final byte[] buf = new byte[8192];


     fos = new new FileOutputStream....

                while ((n = dis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                                counter += n;

                                fos.write(buf, 0, n);

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                         ...
                                    }

                                });
                            }


            if (counter >= file_size) {
                            System.out.println("CLOSED");

                            fos.flush();
                            fos.close();
                            clientSocket.close();

    }
```

Server:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream...
                                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

                                        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[8192];

                                        OutputStream os;
                                        try {
                                            os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                                            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
                                            int read = -1;

                                            while ((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) > -1) {
                                                dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);


                                            }
                                            System.out.println("CLOSED");
                                            dos.flush();
                                            dos.close();
                                            dis.close();

                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();

                                        }
```

What could cause this problem to occur?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How do you connect to socket?

Comment: @mlewandowski I edited my code.

Comment: the server closes connection because buffer overflow error

Comment: @RomanC How can I prevent this error?